# MySQL server taking minutes to answer

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a server and it's systems use NodeJS and MySQL.
When I get a lot of users, the MySQL server takes minutes to answer to the querys.
I have tried everything I could find, nothing worked.

Its just a simple query to see if the user is logged or not, and the server takes minutes to answer, when I make a query trough the SSH terminal (mysql -p) it takes less then 1 second, when I make a query trough MySQL it takes less then 1 second too.

The mysql server is not too overloaded, it gets less then 50 querys/s, the VPS its running have spare RAM, CPU, SSD, etc.

The problem happens in every query that the login servers make, to see if the user is logged, to get information about him, to buy something in the shop.

Thanks so much.

If you need to check the query, here is a query to get information about a test user:

http://maq-1.agariohub.net:4040/info/eyJ0b2tlbiI6IjVyeHU4dnFCQklraklYcjljTzV2Mldsc3FhWGZUdHkySzV6ektSdGg1ZllXYnkyZjYxRVZQUm9VdXFRWE1ZZ2QifQ==

The answer is a JSON, in the end of it it shows how much time it took to perform the two querys the server makes

Comment: Please Post the relevant code

Comment: One of the querys is just: "SELECT id,message FROM warnings WHERE appear = 1 AND user = " + result[0].id + ";"

Comment: When you say "server", you mean your node server takes a minute? I am unclear because ssh and "query through mysql" take < 1s.

Comment: When the nodejs server trys to make a conn.query it takes more then minutes, when I try to make the query from another place like phpmyadmin or even directly trough the mysql console it takes <1s